# How to find nearest nodes in a driving network considering streets directions

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I am trying to compute the distance between 2 points (lat, lon), using `osmnx` package.

While testing `osmnx.nearest_nodes()` to firstly find the nearest node from a point, I noticed that it doesn't seem to take into account the street direction when computing the nearest node (for example when the point is on a one-way street).

For instance : if I take this (lat, lon) point (48.921281, 2.517598), located on a one-way street, the nearest node is found only considering the distance from it (the node n°OSMID 288965181 found with `nearest_nodes()` : 48.9217176, 2.5180361).

`nearest_nodes()` doesn't seem to consider the type of network that I have choosen (drive).
If so, the found node should have been node 288964629 (48.9203235, 2.5166429).

Why ? Because from the point (48.921281, 2.517598), the node 288965181 is not the closest node considering the driving network, while the node 288964629 is.

Here is the code example :

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

#creating the graph from a point coordinates
centreCoord = (48.920576, 2.529185)
G= ox.graph_from_point(centreCoord, dist=2000, network_type='drive')

#origin and destination point
originCoord = (48.921281, 2.517598)
destinationCoord = (48.921454, 2.518696)

#calculating the nearest nodes from origin and destination points
origin_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, originCoord[1], originCoord[0])
destination_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, destinationCoord[1], destinationCoord[0])

#computing the driving path
route = nx.shortest_path(G, source=origin_node, target=destination_node, weight='length')
```

Here a simple plot where :

- the red dot is the origin point (48.921281, 2.517598)
- the blue dot is the destination point (48.921454, 2.518696)
- the green dot is the node 288965181 (48.9217176, 2.5180361)
- the black dot is the node 288965599, the closest dot from the destination point
- the magenta line is the route computed with `networkx.shortest_path()`

I have added :

- the orange dot which is the node 288964629 (48.9203235, 2.5166429) **-> the node that I would like to have as the closest node from the origin point, regarding the direction of traffic (the choosen network type is 'drive')**
- the blue path **-> the route that I should obtained, regarding the direction of traffic**

[Plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM9UL.png)

I might have missed sometimes or done something wrong.

I have read the `osmnx` documentation. I tried several combination (parameters `network_type`, `ox.settings.bidirectional_network_types`), tried to debug the computation in order to understand how the nodes are selected.

Before asking, I have searched for similar topics. A lot of interesting stuff but I didn't find relevant answers.

I am stuck on this for days.

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround could be the following:

1. find the nearest edge from the origin point, using `ox.nearest_edges()` function. You will get the one-way road;
2. the edge is defined by *u*,*v* nodes: u is the starting node of the way, v the ending node, following the street direction;
3. the *v* node is the node you want to be considered (288964629), so compute the route from the *v* node to the destination node.

```
# Get the nearest edge from the origin point
u, v, k = ox.nearest_edges(G, originCoord[1], originCoord[0])

destination_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, destinationCoord[1], destinationCoord[0])

# computing the driving path
route = nx.shortest_path(G, source=v, target=destination_node, weight='length')
```

Here the plot, by using `ox.plot_graph_route(G, route)`: 
[image: plot]

Note that the described approach works fine with one-way roads made of only two nodes.

Comment: Thanks @dnyll ! I didn't think of using `nearest_edges()` in that way. I will implement this approach. One question though : what do you mean by "works fine with one-way roads made of only two nodes" ? Would it be possible to find an edge with more than two nodes ?

Comment: Of course it is still possible... But assume to have a longer one-way road, with many nodes: the approach I described will always choose the ending node of the way as the nearest one from the origin point, instead of the nearest middle nodes

Comment: It's the case for the exmaple I gave: the one-way road of my example is made of multiple nodes. `nearest_edges(G, pointA_lon, pointA_lat)` will return the nearest edge of the road, so I think your approach should still work.

Comment: That's fine then, hope it is the best answer ✅